# BigQuery update an item in repeated field (array)?

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, dml

How to update specific item in repeated field in BigQuery?

For example I just want to update the comments that is match comment's `id = 1`, what is BigQuery SQL syntax for it?

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Data A",
  "comments": [
    {
      "timestamp": 1586333435,
      "id": 1,
      "comment": "Hello World"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1586333635,
      "id": 2,
      "comment": "Hello World 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

My update statement using as follow, but it replace the whole array.

```
UPDATE `projectA.dataSetA.Post`
    SET comments = ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE('Hello World Now' AS comment) FROM UNNEST(comments) AS c WHERE c.id=1)
    WHERE id='1';
```

Comment: You have two ids in the data.  Please show what results you want.

Comment: the id is refer to comment's id

Answer (score 1):

It's the way of querying the way you want it

```
WITH
data AS (
  SELECT 1 as id, 'Data A' as name, 
    [
      STRUCT(1586333435 as timestamp, 1 as id, 'Hello World' as comment),
      STRUCT(1586333635 as timestamp, 2 as id, 'Hello World 2' as comment)
    ] AS comments
)
SELECT id, name, 
  (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(timestamp, id, CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'Hello World Now' ELSE comment END as comment))
    FROM UNNEST(comments)
  )
FROM data
```

So your update statement should be something like:

```
UPDATE `projectA.dataSetA.Post`
    SET comments = (
      SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(timestamp, id, CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'Hello World Now' ELSE comment END as comment))
      FROM UNNEST(comments)
    )
    WHERE id=1;
```

Be careful about IDs. 
Id in the where statement belongs to the data point, id in the case when statement belongs to the comment that should be edited.